# zsh prompt line position not shifting with window resizing

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh

I recently came across `ZSH` and found it very helpful for rails development and git integration. I've follow the setup steps and have my terminal `ZSH`ed. But I found one little annoying thing this morning.

When I'm using `zsh` in the terminal, it looked fined at the start. Like this:
[image]

but When I'm resizing the window and after it's done. The prompt line is not shifting when window is resizing so it gave me an odd look, like this!
[image]

see the red box there? The prompt should be at the top of the window as it was, right? But it didn't, it went down when I'm resizing the window. This is odd...any hints why this is happning? Do I have to fix something in `.zshrc`?

Thanks a lot in advance!

BTW: I'm using latest Mac OSX. Maverick

Comment: This seems like a simple screen redraw problem.  Does pressing CMD-R fix the issue, or does it remain half-way down the screen?

Comment: Also, this may be a better question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: nope CMD-R is not working. I'll try to ask on serverfault.com thanks!

Comment: Could you put a link to your serverfault question? I have the exact same problem and I'd love to have a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I also have this problem and I don't have a solution but here's one thing I have noticed.
It's that this isn't a problem when using `bash` as your default shell. So I started to look into it. When bash runs it looks to `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile` loads `/etc/bashrc`. When I looked in `/etc/bashrc` there was one line that seems like it might be related:

```
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

I'm not sure if this is related or not but when I run that command in `zsh` I get:

```
zsh: command not found: shopt
```

Perhaps someone more familiar with bash/zsh/osx can make more sense of this.

Comment: I reinstalled zsh and it seem to fix the problem but I think yours is the correct solution!